# declare a class member function as a friend function of another class

Tags: c++, friend-function

i have created 2 classes (class A and class B) i have declared class A before class B(forward declaration of class A). i have created a public function in class B with name funB(A temp). in the class A i have declared the funB function of class B as a friend function of class A.

**i am getting error when i write the defination of funB() inside the class B defination. but when i write the defination of funB() function outside the class B then it works fine.**

can anyone explain why this is happening ????
i am very confused.

```
// ERROR
class A;
class B{
    public:
        void funB(A temp){
            printf("friend function");
        }
};

class A{
    public:
        friend void B::funB(A);
};
```

above code has showing me ERROR

the below code works fine.

```
class A;
class B{
    public:
        void funB(A temp);
};

class A{
    public:
        friend void B::funB(A);
};

void B::funB(A temp){
    printf("friend function");
}
```

please answer to my problem.

Comment: Forward declaration is usually used only with a pointer or a reference to a class (because the compiler does not need to know the full class definition for that). I'm actually surprised that the 2nd piece is accepted. I guess that only if you suply a definition for `B::funB` the compiler is bothered by the missing defintion for `A` (as in the 1st piece).

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please take the [tour] and read [ask]. This will grant you your first badge. And please note that questions about a compiler error are always easier to answer when you include the compiler error in the question. In this case the message should tell you exactly the reason why one code is fine the other not. If you dont understand, no problem, show us the error message and we can explain it.

Comment: @wholstad in the second code `void funB(A temp);` is merely a declaration. Perhaps writing `void funB(class A temp)` would make it more clear that its fine without definition of `A`.

Comment: *"above code has showing me ERROR"* -- Usually error messages are a bit more descriptive than just "Error". Typically, they tell you what the error is. *(You did copy-paste the full error message into your question, right?)*

Comment: @463035818_is_not_an_ai I see, this makes sense. Happy to learn something new. As I wrote I'm used to associating a pointer or a reference with the usage of a forward declaration. +1 for your answer.

Answer (score 2):

This has nothing to do with friends. `void funB(A temp)` requires `A` to be a complete type. `A` must be defined before you can define `B::funB` because implicitly it uses methods of `A` (a copy is made to copy a parameter to the argument of the function, then when the function returns `temp` must be destroyed by calling a destructor).

In the first example you try to define `B::funB` before `A` is complete. Thats an error.

In the second example you define `B::funB` when `A` is complete.

PS: I suppose reading the error message would have helped to understand. It should mention something about `A` being incomplete when you define `B::funB`.